# read a zipfile without knowing file name in python

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I have a zip file in a directory. I want to read out the contents of the zipfile and after this move its content to other directories to auto sort my zipped files. thing is, the name of these zipfiles will change everytime.
I learned about glob being able to handle the asterix for this normally, but it doesn't work with the zipfile import.

I tried:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from glob import glob

path_to_zip = glob(r"C:\me\Python\map_dumper\*.zip")

with ZipFile(path_to_zip, "r") as read_zip:
   ZipFile.namelist()
```

This gives me an AttributeError:'list' object has no attribute 'seek'

anyone know of another solution for this?

Comment: `glob()` returns a list of filenames and `ZipFile` only accepts a single filename. Iterate over the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) gives you *list* of filenames compliant with what you specify, for example

```
glob(r"C:\me\Python\map_dumper\*.zip")
```

is list of *all* zip files inside map_dumper catalog, you might use `for` loop to apply your action to every such file following way

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from glob import glob

files_list = glob(r"C:\me\Python\map_dumper\*.zip")

for path_to_zip in files_list:
    with ZipFile(path_to_zip, "r") as read_zip:
        ZipFile.namelist()
```